# Aws Api Gateway - ERR_ABORTED 403 - NOT LOADING JS AND CSS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, http-status-code-403

I built rest api in aws api gateway. It has proxy integration. The problem is that **url does not load javascript or css files.**

These are some errors in console of browser:

> GET https://....amazonaws.com/s1997.css net::ERR_ABORTED 403

> GET https://....amazonaws.com/g2669.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403

> GET https://....amazonaws.com/favicon.ico 403

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

"Authorization None" and "API Key Not required" in api.

**EDIT:**

This url has 403 error:
https://...amazonaws.com/static/main.css

However, when I add stage to url, I get all css: https://...amazonaws.com/ProxyStage/static/main.css

How can solve these errors so that I can run the url with javascript and css files?